# Return list of all nodes from xml column in sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm working on an SQL database and I need a way to return a list of all products that have a tag attached to them. Here's a quick example of my xml

```
<ArrayOfString>
  <string>fee</string>
  <string>activation</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

I also have a column for ProductType and ProductID. What I need to do is pull out all entries of a certain product type, and list off the different strings in the xml column. So what I need to see for example is something like...

```
------------------------------------------------
PRODUCTID     |      TAG       |  PRODUCT TYPE
------------------------------------------------
    1         |      fee       |   1
    1         |   activation   |   1  
    2         |      fee       |   1 
    3         |      fee       |   1
```

So basically if the xml in that column has more than 1 'string' node, I need to know EACH node, and the productID that it goes with.

I've tried using Tags.values() and Tags.query() to get my values, and I can get close in as much as it returns values like...

```
------------------------------------------------
PRODUCTID     |      TAG       |  PRODUCT TYPE
------------------------------------------------
    1         | <string>fee</st|   1
    2         |      fee       |   1 
    3         |      fee       |   1
```

but this lumps all of the strings together in one view...

Also, I was trying to sort that out since I could make that work, and was trying to say

```
SELECT ProductID, Tags.query('/ArrayOfString/string') AS AttachedTags
FROM dbo.products 
WHERE ProductType = 1
    ORDER BY AttachedTags
```

but it says that AttachedTags is not a valid column name... any ideas on if I'm trying to sort it out by certain tags first?

Comment: hey marc_s, sorry about that delay - I was using MSS, thanks for updating my tags! To anyone else, see JamieSee's answer below for a good example of cross apply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to break down multiple nodes with the same name you need to use CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductTags.Tag.value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS AttachedTag
FROM dbo.products 
CROSS APPLY Tags.nodes('/ArrayOfString/string/text()') as ProductTags(Tag)
WHERE ProductType = 1
ORDER BY AttachedTag
```

Comment: Dude you rock. I had tried the CROSS APPLY, but I think I see my issue now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use as

Select YOUR_COLUMN.value('(YOUR_NODES)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') From YOUR_TABLE

like

```
xml.value('(/form/NotesSection/Nt-Status)[1]','VARCHAR(100)')
```

Comment: Umm not really helpful. You're just stating how to statically query an XML field which isn't what he asked.